# Synonyms for "little by little"

Tags: phrases, synonyms

What are some other ways I can say something that means the same thing as "little by little"? The only other thing I know is "bit by bit."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few *—by—* phrases at your disposal. The established ones, besides *little by little* are: [*step by step*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1294221#m_en_us1294221.055), [*day by day*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1238506#m_en_us1238506.048), [*inch by inch*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1257497#m_en_us1257497.019), and [*bit by bit*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1226770#m_en_us1226770.017). You can also construct any of your own choosing, depending on the context, e.g. *moment by moment*, *sip by sip*, *limp by limp*, and even *wiggle by wiggle*!

The plainest one-word synonym would be [*gradually*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1419110#m_en_us1419110). Other possible adverbs you could use in its place are: [*steadily*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1294083#m_en_us1294083.018), [*slowly*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1291505#m_en_us1291505), [*progressively*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1281028#m_en_us1281028.017) and [*incrementally*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1257600#m_en_us1257600.008).†

I would also recommend the synonymous phrases, [*slowly but surely*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1291505#m_en_us1291505.003) and [*by degrees*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1239101#m_en_us1239101.018http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1239101#m_en_us1239101.018).

---

<sup>†Credit goes to [Martha](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1547/martha) for this suggestion.</sup>

Comment: Also: *incrementally.*

Comment: @Martha: Oh, definitely!! Brilliant inclusion, thanks!

Comment: @Martha: beat me to it! Upvoted accordingly.

Comment: Hehe, wiggle by wiggle.

Comment: Brings to mind that old Three Stooges bit, "Niagara Falls! Slowly I turned, step by step, inch by inch..." Turns out this was a classic Vaudeville trope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_I_Turned

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps 'gradually' may fit your needs, as it also suggests progression in small increments.

Answer (score 2):

You could also say

> A little bit at a time

Answer (score -1):

"Softly, softly, catchy monkey" is one that springs to mind, with a variation that kind of conveys the same meaning as "slowly but surely", which is:

"Slowly, slowly, catchy monkey" - kind of cute, yet meaningless?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.